# Are taxis available on the Israel side of the northern crossing to Jordan?

Tags: borders, israel, taxis, jordan

After touring in Jordan, my guide will let me off on the Jordan side of the Beit She’an / Sheik Hussein – Northern border crossing (between Tiberias and Jerash).  Is there a taxi stand on the Israel side of the border that has taxis waiting for hire during daylight hours?  If not, how can I get a taxi there to take me to Tiberias?

Answer (score 7):

The official page for the Nehar Yarden (Jordan River) crossing, as the Israelis call it, says that [your best option is taxi](http://www.iaa.gov.il/en-US/borders/NeharYarden/Pages/default.aspx), and like any other Middle East border crossing, I'd expect a few to be hanging around.  You/somebody can probably call you a cab in a pinch though.

[Bus 16](http://bus.co.il/otobusimmvc/Line_Places/1010/16_15_-1433419596) also runs between Beit Shean and the border (stop #8), but there are only a [few services per day](http://bus.co.il/otobusimmvc/Line_Travels/1010/16_15_-1433419596), and (as usual in Israel) none on Shabbat.

Comment: If there are no taxis hanging around, is there a local taxi company that I could call?  If so, how long might it take for that local company to provide a taxi?  (I will be traveling with some young children and would like to be careful about arrangements.)

Comment: It's <10 km to Beit Shean, so an available taxi should be there in minutes.  Google for a local company, or use Israel's version of Uber, GetTaxi.

Comment: Is there connectivity at the border crossing?

Comment: We took bus #16 yesterday, it doesn't go to the border crossing, but turns about 2km before and yes there are only a few a day.  I didn't notice any taxis but I also didn't look for them.